# How to delete a java class in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class

I have created a new Java class in Android Studio by following this:

```
File => New => Java class.
```

And now I want to delete this class. What should I do?

Comment: If you are on Windows, try with Right Click on the file & select `Delete`. If on Mac just select the file & press `Command + delete`

Answer (score 0):

Select File you want to delete.
Then press "delete" button (or "command+backspace" for MacOS)